# pthread_cond_timedwait doesn't work even if I use absolute time

Tags: c++, c, linux, time, pthreads

I'm using this code to try to get the `main`thread to wait around for a bit, but it doesn't work at all.

The code is as follows.

```
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
using namespace std;
int64_t get_current_millis(void) 
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return (int64_t)tv.tv_sec * 1000 + tv.tv_usec / 1000;
}


int main()
{
    pthread_mutex_t Mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_cond_t Condition = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

    uint64_t start_ts = get_current_millis();

    struct timeval now;
    struct timespec interval;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&Mutex);
    gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
    interval.tv_sec = now.tv_sec;
    interval.tv_nsec = now.tv_usec * 1000;
    interval.tv_sec += 5;
    pthread_cond_timedwait(&Condition, &Mutex, &interval);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&Mutex);

    uint64_t end_ts = get_current_millis();
    std::cout << "wait " << (end_ts - start_ts)/1000 << "s" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I use absolute time. BUT it prints:

```
wait 0s
```

Any solutions? Thank you very much.

Comment: In C++ there is `std::condition_variable` for that. Please choose the language.

Comment: You should at least check the value returned by `pthread_cond_timedwait`.  Are you sure you're not just getting a spurious wakeup?

Comment: Are you compiling (and linking) with `-pthread` (if using GCC or clang)?

Comment: `gettimeofday(&now, NULL);` instead use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME`

Comment: Thanks. It' really nice of all of you. I forget to add ```-lpthread```. it goes well after I add it.

Comment: @Mat would that not generate a link error?

Comment: @MartinJames: not in this instance. Compiles and links (to things in libc that, apparently, do nothing).

Comment: @Mat, OK, thanks, (that is just weird..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is given by @Mat. Thank all. It' really nice of all of you.